# Dell Inspiron 11-3162 Home | End | PgUp | PgDn keys not working

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I just recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x86_64 on a brand new Dell Inspiron 11-3162 2.0.0. Everything works as expected except the "Home | End | PgUp | PgDn" functionality.

On this particular keyboard you have to hit Fn+LeftArrow for Home, or Fn+RightArrow for End, Fn+UpArrow for PgUp and Fn+DownArrow for PgDn. The crazy part is the **first time** I use one of these functions it works. But if I try and go "home" or "end" a second time, nothing happens. I have to reboot to be able to do it again for the first time, and then nothing the second time.

Also, the Function key **does work** with all other features... so for example the Fn+F3 increases the volume - works great. Fn+F12 brightens the screen - works great. Fn+F1 mutes the sound - works great, etc. Just the Fn+ArrowKeys is giving me a problem, and only on subsequent uses.

Is there any direction to find a solution anyone can provide?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem with this model laptop after installing 16.04. The showkey command showed key presses but no key releases for the fn+arrow keys. I think it was a problem with a specific kernel version as the problem went away after an update and reboot.